# Maximum records in function module "tables" parameter

Tags: abap, function-module

What's the maximum number of records that can be passed to a function module via a tables parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never hit max in a function call. But have in other programs.

[from sap](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb35de358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) it depends on the type of table.

> The maximum memory that can be
>   occupied by an internal table
>   (including its internal
>   administration) is 2 gigabytes. A more
>   realistic figure is up to 500
>   megabytes. An additional restriction
>   for hashed tables is that they may not
>   contain more than 2 million entries.

Answer (score 2):

While it will depend on the type of table. You will hit other walls like memory allocation and no roll memory. Since everything you're doing will be resident in a WA the primary concern will be memory. If you plan on running this in the background and not as a Dialog user, you will still have to be cognizant of how much memory and page swap space you're consuming.